# Java EE Web App Plugin Architecture

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have a simple Web App that receives data via a web service and persists it in a database.  I am using CXF, Hibernate and Glassfish 3.  I am very new to all of this, however I am trying to work out how I can develop a simple plugin model so that when the App fisrt starts up it searches for plugin's in a folder and calls an instantiation(?) class for each plugin.  The issue is that I am not really sure how to initiate this process (that is when the App firsts starts) - how do I know when the app first starts.  Any advice/comments appreciated!

ok here is a sample class with the modification of web.xml:

```
package foo.bar.startup;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class AppStartup implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // App started - do start up stuff
    }
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // App stopped - do something
    }
}




  <listener>
    <listener-class>foo.bar.AppStartup</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a web application starts, it fires a `ServletContextEvent` which goes to every registered [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). These listeners must be configured in the web.xml of the application:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.foo.bar.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Thank you - I really appreciate the guidance.  I have tested some code and it works well - I will add and example above for others.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know when the app starts / stops, you can implement a [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and register it in the web.xml file.

You should look at OSGI - if you need an elaborate plugin model, with support for deploying new plugins at runtime, hot redeployment of plugins etc.